# Force ASP.NET textbox to display currency with $ sign

Tags: asp.net, formatting, textbox, currency

Is there a way to get an ASP.NET textbox to accept only currency values, and when the control is validated, insert a $ sign beforehand?

Examples:

10.23 becomes $10.23
$1.45 stays $1.45
10.a raises error due to not being a valid number

I have a RegularExpressionValidator that is verifying the number is valid, but I don't know how to force the $ sign into the text.  I suspect JavaScript might work, but was wondering if there was another way to do this.

Comment: I ended up figuring out some JavaScript to do what I wanted.  Needed to simplify a deployment package and the AJAX toolkit was just another dependency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ASP.NET [MaskedEdit](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/MaskedEdit) control from the [AJAX Control Toolkit](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki) can accomplish what you're asking for.

Comment: MaskedEdit link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but I wanted to throw out another solution for anyone with the same problem and looking for multiple workarounds.

The way I do this is to use jQuery [format currency plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) to bind user input on the client side.  Parsing this input on the server side only requires:

```
// directive
using System.Globalization;

// code
decimal input = -1;
if (decimal.TryParse(txtUserInput.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out input))
{
    parameter = input.ToString();
}
```

The only downfall to this is that the user can have javascript turned off, in which case the RegEx validator running server-side would work as a fall-back.  If the control is databound, all you have to do is `decimalValue.ToString("{0:c}")` , as mentioned by others, in order to display the proper currency formatting.

The cool thing about this is that if the user enters the textbox and it shows `$0.00` on the client side, the server-side if statement would return false.  If your decimal value isn't nullable in the database, just change `decimal input = -1` to `decimal input = 0` and you'll have a default value of 0.

Comment: Sure thing! It's very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this might be to place the dollar sign outside to the left of the text box.  Is there a real need to have the dollar sign inside of the box or will a simple label do?

Comment: There is no real need for it, I am unfortnately tied to the sales and marketing requirements.  I tried arguing against it, but was overruled.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal sValue = decimal.Parse(txtboxValue.Text.Trim());
// Put Code to check whether the $ sign already exist or not.
//Try making a function returning boolean
//if Dollar sign not available do this
{ string LableText = string.Format("{0:c}", sValue); }
else
{ string LableText = Convert.ToString(sValue); }
```

Comment: string.Format("{0:c}", sValue) is a nice solution when you need to place the value in a label sometimes and a textbox at other times.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sValue = Convert.ToString(txtboxValue.Text.Trim());
// Put Code to check whether the $ sign already exist or not.
//Try making a function returning boolean
//if Dollar sign not available do this
{ string LableText = string.Format("{0:c}", "sValue"); }
else
{ string LableText = Convert.ToString(sValue); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .CS you could do a pattern match along the lines of,

```
string value = text_box_to_validate.Text;

string myPattern = @"^\$(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(\.\d{0,2})|\d{1,3}(\.\d{2})|\.\d{2})$";
Regex r = new Regex(myPattern);
Match m = r.Match(value);

if (m.Success)
{
    //do something -- everything passed
}
else
{
    //did not match
    //could check if number is good, but is just missing $ in front
}
```

Comment: Already running that regex.  I want the $ sign to be inserted into the textbox value after the value is entered, preferably without a postback.