# How to write 5 as 5.00 on ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force ASP.NET textbox to display currency with $ sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202067/force-asp-net-textbox-to-display-currency-with-sign)
>   [In jQuery, what's the best way of formatting a number to 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

I've a textbox control on my ASP.NET page which accepts amount of Money.
If it is entered as 500, I want to display it as 500.00.Using textchanged event I couldn't solve the problem in C#.Hope javascript will do it.Can anyone help me out by providing the required javascript or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

For your text box put the `AutoPostBack="true"` and in the page load event write the following code part

```
        if (IsPostBack == true)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ".00";
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

If that's the case then write the code like below.

```
        if (IsPostBack) 
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0) 
            {
                if (TextBox1.Text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ".00";
                }
                else if (TextBox1.Text.EndsWith(".")) 
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "00"; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) 
                    {
                        if (TextBox1.Text.EndsWith("." + i)) 
                        {
                            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "0";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Sukanya, see the edited code now.

Comment: you edited my Code?? ok any how post the little modification in Comment I will edit it.

Comment: @Sukanya, see the code now its ok.

Comment: I'm deleting my comments on the above discussion..

Comment: Ok, Thankyou. as you given to put the code for checking up to 9 from 0, so i have changed it to simple for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Formatted string (eg .ToString("##.###")
2. Using javascript and appending 0's

Comment: where and how will I format?and if you can provide me the javascript code please give...