# Display 5 as 5.00 in textbox control in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript

I've a textbox control on my ASP.NET page which accepts amount of Money. If it is entered as 500,after leaving the textbox control, I want to appear it as 500.00.Using textchanged event I couldn't solve the problem in C#.Hope javascript will do it.Can anyone help me out by providing the required javascript or any other way?

Comment: Do you use jQuery or some other javascript library?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write 5 as 5.00 on ASP.NET Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118213/how-to-write-5-as-5-00-on-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this in this fashion, make a javascript function and call it on the `onblur` event of the textbox

```
var txt ='5'; // ur value in textbox    
var decimalplace = new Number(parseFloat(txt)); // say you have values like 5.15747
alert(decimalplace.toFixed(2)); // gotta get 5.00
```

Comment: Thank u.It's working if there is no auto post back=true for any other control in the form.The moment another control's value is being changed,this textbox control is showing 0.00  .It's not holding back the previously entered amount.

Comment: ya,we are using viewstate to hold diffeterent state of the page.

Comment: Did the above thing help you achieve the format ? else please do key in your answer

Comment: yes,it helped me to dispaly the numberas I wanted to.thanks a lot.

Comment: If yes then do please mark this as answer, click on the check mark next to the answer .. will help for all those who stumble upon this later